# Show Empty list message only after Loader get ended in React Native using Flat list

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a flat list, which gets its data source as a state. Actually, this data is from firebase, and i have been using redux. So, the data is fetched in the actions, and using callback i get the data to state.

What i want to achieve is, when there is no data found from the api, An empty list message should be show in the view. Actually , i achieved this using "ListEmptyComponent". But whats happening is the screen starts with empty message, and the spinner loads below it, and then if data found the message goes away as well as spinner.

But, what i wanted is, when the view gets rendered the first thing everyone should see is the spinner, and then if data empty spinner hides then empty list message displays.

How to achieve this ?

My Action :

```
export const fetchOrderHistory = (phone, callback) => {
return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: START_SPINNER_ACTION_FOR_ORDER_HISTORY })
    firebase.database().ref('orders/'+phone)
    .on('value', snapshot => {
        const snapShotValue = snapshot.val();
        callback(snapShotValue);
        dispatch ({ type: ORDER_HISTORY_FETCHED , payload: snapshot.val()});
        dispatch({ type: STOP_SPINNER_ACTION_FRO_ORDER_HISTORY })
    });

};
```

};

My Flat List & spinner:

```
<FlatList
                        data={this.state.historyOfOrders}
                        keyExtractor={item => item.uid}
                        ListEmptyComponent={this.onListEmpty()}
                        renderItem={({ item }) => (
                            <Card
                            containerStyle={{ borderRadius: 5 }}
                            >
                            <View style={styles.topContainerStyle}>
                                    <View>
                                        <TouchableOpacity
                                        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ViewOrderScreen', {itemsOfOrder: item}) }
                                        >
                                            <View style={styles.viewOrderContainer}>
                                            <View style={styles.viewOrderTextContainer}>
                                                <Text style={styles.viewOrderTextStyle}>View Order</Text>
                                            </View>
                                            <Icon 
                                            name='ios-arrow-forward'
                                            type='ionicon'
                                            color='#ff7675'
                                            />
                                            </View>
                                        </TouchableOpacity>
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                        </Card> 
                        )}
                    />

                    {this.props.isSpinnerLoading &&
                    <View style={styles.loading}>
                        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#03A9F4"/>
                    </View> }
```

My Call back at componentWillMount which set state:

```
 componentWillMount() {
   this.props.fetchOrderHistory((this.props.phone), (snapShotValue)=> {
        const userOrderHistory = _.map(snapShotValue, (val,uid) => ({uid, ...val}))
        this.setState({ historyOfOrders: userOrderHistory })
   });
}
```

My EmptyList Message:

```
onListEmpty = () => {
   return <View style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }}>
        <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 25 }}>No Data</Text>
    </View>
}
```

My State:

```
state = { historyOfOrders: "" }
```

I am getting the spinner values from the reducers, using mapStateToProps.

Kindly Guide me, through

Answer (score 2):

you have to do two things for that.
First, show Flatlist only if the loader is stopped. Second, set default value of `this.state.historyOfOrders` is null and check if this.state.historyOfOrders not null then only show Flatlist.

Here is a code:

```
{(!this.props.isSpinnerLoading && this.state.historyOfOrders != null) ? 
    (
    <FlatList
        data={this.state.historyOfOrders}
        keyExtractor={item => item.uid}
        ListEmptyComponent={this.onListEmpty()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Card containerStyle={{ borderRadius: 5 }}>
                <View style={styles.topContainerStyle}>
                    <View>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ViewOrderScreen', {itemsOfOrder: item}) }>
                            <View style={styles.viewOrderContainer}>
                                <View style={styles.viewOrderTextContainer}>
                                    <Text style={styles.viewOrderTextStyle}>View Order</Text>
                                </View>
                                <Icon 
                                name='ios-arrow-forward'
                                type='ionicon'
                                color='#ff7675'
                                />
                            </View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Card> 
        )}
    /> 
    ) : null
}
```

With this condition, even if you want loader above Flatlist you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

The path you should take is rendering only the spinner when the loading flag is set and rendering the list when loading flag is false.
Your render method should be like below

```
render()
{

   if(this.props.isSpinnerLoading)
   {
       return (<View style={styles.loading}>
                        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#03A9F4"/>
                    </View> );
   }

   return (/** Actual List code here **/);
}
```